# Send POST To Different Website (ASP.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

What is the VB.NET (or C#) code to prepare POST data and send to a different website than specified in the current `<form ...>` section?

EDIT: Every algorithm I've found online using `HttpWebRequest` gets the returning page from the other site and outputs it with `Response.Write`.  I want to navigate to the new page posting the data and leaving the current page completely.

EDIT2: (more specific description of what I want)
The code below displays a line chart.  When the user clicks on the label for a data point, the page refreshes (performs a postback) and displaying the x-value of the clicked point.

Instead, upon clicking a label, I want to send `other_id="#VALX"` as the only POST data to `other_results.aspx` as if the user had typed the corresponding `id` into the the `TextBox` on `other_search.aspx` and clicked `Submit`.

How can I do that?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OracleClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Chart1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageMapEventArgs)
        Response.Write(e.PostBackValue)
    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" OnClick="Chart1_Click"
            DataSourceID="myDataSource">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line"
                    IsValueShownAsLabel="true" XValueMember="id"
                    YValueMembers="value" PostBackValue="#VALX" />
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" />
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="myDataSource" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnStr %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnStr.ProviderName %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT id, value FROM myTable"
            DataSourceMode="DataReader"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to send a `POST` request from your C#/VB.NET page to another website you want to take a look at the [HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Comment: Dang!  I was going to add that to my answer, but you beat me to it. Good job!  +1 to you.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything with the form contents - if you simply want to post it to another server, see the first half of my answer.  Just put in a simple html form like you would if this were an html page.

Comment: Edited main post again with a more specific example of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="someotherwebsite/someotherform">
.....
</form>
```

In other words, just create a standard html form.  Don't include the 'runat="server"' in the Form tag, and it will be treated as a standard html form.  You CAN have more than one Form tag in an apsx page.  You can only have one with runat="Server" set, but you can have other forms on your page, so long as they are not nested.

*Edit*

However, if you need to do some server-side processing of your own and you want to send the post data in addtition to the work YOU need to do server-side, then you can call the other site's form using the WebRequest class (as @Chris Pebble said, when he beat me to the second part of my intended answer.)

Comment: Edited main post again with a more specific example of what I am trying to accomplish.